# Fadeout + empty a div, and then put new content in

Tags: jquery, fadeout, jquery-effects

What is a good way to fadeout the **content** of a div, but keeping the div ready for new content?

With

```
$('#info').html('').fadeOut(500);
or
$('#info').fadeOut(500).html('').show();
```

The div content just disappears, and new content does not show

With

```
 $('#info').fadeOut(500);
```

The div fades as it should, but any new content does not show

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
$('#info').fadeOut(500, function() {
   $(this).empty().show();
});
```

Comment: +1 for using `empty()` instead of `html('')` since that's what it's there for.

Comment: What would be the method for setting content to a div and fading it in then? EDIT: Ah got it: $('#info').hide().html('new content').fadeIn(200); Is that the best way?

Comment: Yes, you don't need a callback when fading in!

Answer (score 6):

```
$('#info').fadeOut(500, function() {
   $(this).html('').show();
});
```

Will wait until the div is faded out before emtying it!

Answer (score 2):

Use fadeOut's callback:

```
$('#info').fadeOut(500, function() {
  $('#info').html("New Content").show();
});
```

Comment: You can use `$(this)` instead of finding the element again. :)